# Fictional interactive map with leaflet script issue between leaflet 0.6.4 and leaflet 0.7.3

Tags: html, dictionary, leaflet

I tried to create a map a while back using leaflet 0.6.4 and worked fine but when I tried to switch to leaflet 0.7.3 no tile was uploaded. The main error in my html debugger was "Map" Container not found.

The code was never hosted on an webserver because A)I don't have the money and B)I'm not tech savy enough (YET!) to know how to work. So I've mostly tested the code localy (Click on C:/ file is here/ test.html).

If anyone can help me understand what I did I wrong, I would grateful.

Here's the code:

```
<head>
<title>Region1-7</title>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.6.4/leaflet.css" />
<!--[if lte IE 8]>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.6.4/leaflet.ie.css" />
<![endif]-->
<script src="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.6.4/leaflet.js"></script>
<script>
    function init() {
        var mapMinZoom = 0;
        var mapMaxZoom = 5;
        var map = L.map('map', {
            maxZoom: mapMaxZoom,
            minZoom: mapMinZoom,
            crs: L.CRS.Simple
        }).setView([0, 0], mapMaxZoom);

        var mapBounds = new L.LatLngBounds(
            map.unproject([0, 5632], mapMaxZoom),
            map.unproject([5632, 0], mapMaxZoom));

        map.fitBounds(mapBounds);
        L.tileLayer('{z}/map_{x}_{y}.png', {
            minZoom: mapMinZoom,
            maxZoom: mapMaxZoom,
            bounds: mapBounds,
            attribution: 'Rendered by the God Emperor of Mankind',
            noWrap: true
        }).addTo(map);
    }
</script>
<style>
    html,
    body,
    #map {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
</style>
</head>

<body onload="init()">
<div id="map"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

If anyone has any ressource about Free webhosting for testing purposes or self-learning documentation about leaflet I'm all ears.

Hell, if you folks have any commentary I'm open to mostly anything...Except you Dan...He knows what he did....

Answer (score 0):

You can fix this by setting `continuousWorld: true` for your tile layer.

> If set to `true`, the tile coordinates won't be wrapped by world width (-180 to 180 longitude) or clamped to lie within world height (-90 to 90). Use this if you use Leaflet for maps that don't reflect the real world (e.g. game, indoor or photo maps).

Source: http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#tilelayer-continuousworld

See perliedman's comment for more information: https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/issues/2579#issuecomment-38657771